# Python Detects URL and Removes It in Text File

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter

I have taken a Python script from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103888/by-beautiful-soup-i-scrape-twitter-data-i-am-able-to-get-data-but-cant-save-in) and edited it to fit my liking, where I print the first twenty Tweets from a particular page scraped to a text file.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file = "tweets.txt"
f = open(file, "w")
url = "https://twitter.com/BBCWorld"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Gets the tweet
tweets = soup.find_all("li", attrs = {"class":"js-stream-item"})

# Writes tweet fetched in file
for tweet in tweets:
   try:
    if tweet.find('p',{'tweet-text'}):
       tweet_text = tweet.find('p',{'tweet-text'}).text.encode('utf8').strip()
       # tweet_user = tweet.find('span',{"class":'username'}).text.strip()
       # replies = tweet.find('span',{"class":"ProfileTweet-actionCount"}).text.strip()
       # retweets = tweet.find('span', {"class" : "ProfileTweet-action--retweet"}).text.strip()
       # String interpolation technique
       f.write(f'{tweet_text}\n')
  except: AttributeError
f.close()
```

However, when the Tweets are printed there, they look like this (I'm using BBCWorld's feed as an example):

```
b'Van crash in south-east Iran kills 28 Afghan nationalshttps://bbc.in/2qcsg9P\xc2\xa0' 

b'Guernsey asbestos cancer compensation scheme to launchhttps://bbc.in/2qQD9OE\xc2\xa0'

b'Construction firm fined \xc2\xa310k for Jersey water pollutionhttps://bbc.in/2KgIk19\xc2\xa0'

b'US election 2020: Deval Patrick announces presidential bidhttps://bbc.in/32QbdHH\xc2\xa0'

b'Knottfield: Joseph Marshall indecent assault trial delayedhttps://bbc.in/2XcXYjg\xc2\xa0'

b"Hugo Carvajal: Venezuelan ex-spy chief's disappearance 'a scandal'https://bbc.in/34VIwdY\xc2\xa0"

b'What fate awaits those former members of Islamic State being expelled from Turkey?https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/50396607\xc2\xa0'

b"Notre Dame: Army general tells architect to 'shut his mouth'https://bbc.in/2qVP7pX\xc2\xa0"

b'Six years after a Boeing 737-500 crashed in Kazan, Russian investigators conclude that the pilot wasn\xe2\x80\x99t qualified to fly the plane & had used falsified documents to get his job with (now defunct) Tatarstan Airlines. 50 people were killed.'

b'South Africa rugby stars strip off for cancer challengehttps://bbc.in/2rJF2Nv\xc2\xa0'

b"Diabetes: UN to tackle 'overly expensive' insulin priceshttps://bbc.in/2Op0nUf\xc2\xa0"

b'US Senator blocks move to say Armenian mass killing was genocidehttps://bbc.in/2QfjjHr\xc2\xa0'

b"Turkey to extradite American IS suspect 'stranded on border'https://bbc.in/33OJ1X1\xc2\xa0"

b'Father and daughter ballet video breaks stereotypes, says teacherhttps://bbc.in/2KlFEPY\xc2\xa0'

b'Australia seeks to curb foreign interference in universitieshttps://bbc.in/2NJcb4i\xc2\xa0'

b'Washington teacher arrested for threatening to shoot studentshttps://bbc.in/2KlUk1o\xc2\xa0'

b'Denmark holds neo-Nazi over Jewish cemetery attackhttps://bbc.in/2pjrcR9\xc2\xa0'

b'Manus Island refugee author Behrouz Boochani arrives in New Zealandhttps://bbc.in/2NMI4cs\xc2\xa0'

b'Italy to declare state of emergency over damage from Venice floodshttp://bbc.in/2OdDoeu\xc2\xa0'

b'Condor Ferries bought by Swedish investment fundhttps://bbc.in/2NLw0rT\xc2\xa0'
```

How do I remove the "b's"? And, how can I make it so that I can remove the URL if the particular Tweet has that link, like all of these do?

Additionally, why are there sometimes strings of numbers and letters that appear, and how can these be fixed/removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the b's, you'd want to do something like:

`str_tweet = tweet_text.decode('utf-8')`

To get rid of the hyperlinks at the end you *could* do something like this, which is quick and dirty:

`only_tweet = str_tweet.split('https://')[0]`

And then of course change your write statement to point to the new variable. This will result in output like:

`'Van crash in south-east Iran kills 28 Afghan nationals'`

instead of

`b'Van crash in south-east Iran kills 28 Afghan nationalshttps://bbc.in/2qcsg9P\xc2\xa0'`